# Durable Functions Orchestration missing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

Was trying to create a new Azure Durable Function in Visual Studio 2017, but couldnt find the "Durable Functions Orchestration" listed in the below popup:

[image]

My visual studio is up to date, and not sure what I am missing!!

Answer (score 10):

Ok, Found the problem.  It seems like we need to select "Azure Functions v2 (.NET Core)" as the framework when creating the Project.

[image]

**Note:  After the project is created, do a build/rebuild of the project before trying to add a new function.  For some reason, when I tried to add new Item, it still wasnt listed until I built the project**

After the project is built successfully, you should now be able to see "Durable Functions Orchestration"

[image]